# Linux/RHEL5: UDP on IPv6 does not work on the same pc

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, ipv6

I try to setup a netcat server/client with UDP and IPv6 on the same pc.

Here are my interfaces on my pc:

```
[root@rh55hp360g7ss7 trunk_dir]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xxx
          inet addr:192.168.255.166  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1ec1:deff:fef3:4870/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21948499 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24300265 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:360733 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3645218404 (3.3 GiB)  TX bytes:1672728274 (1.5 GiB)
          Interrupt:162 Memory:f4000000-f4012800
```

Then I start the netcat server:

```
nc -6ul fe80::1ec1:deff:fef3:4870%eth0 5678
```

And the netcat client (still on the same pc)

```
nc -6u fe80::1ec1:deff:fef3:4870%eth0 5678
```

But then, when I type something into the NetCat Client, nothing is transfered to the server.

The same example is working if

- I start the netcat client on another pc
- I'm using TCP instead of UDP (i.e. when I remove the -u option)
- When I'm using IPv4 instead of IPv6 (i.e. when I remove the -6 option and if I take the IPv4 address).

Any Ideas?

TSohr.

Here is the routing table, in case it might help:

```
[root@rh55hp360g7ss7 trunk_dir]# route -A inet6
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                                 Next Hop                                Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
fe80::/64                                   *                                       U     256    0        0 eth0
::1/128                                     *                                       U     0      265       5 lo
fe80::1ec1:deff:fef3:4870/128               *                                       U     0      10551       1 lo
ff00::/8                                    *                                       U     256    0        0 eth0
[root@rh55hp360g7ss7 trunk_dir]#
```

## Added 2012-03-13

- With ::1, it is working.
- I have the same problem when trying to run a SIP stack on the pc.

Comment: Does localhost (`::1`) work?  I'd try not to use the link-local addresses for anything.

Comment: The bind address should not include the zone specifier (%eth0). It is also advised to use *socat* and *ip route* instead (of netcat, route), for its/their greater flexibility.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Might be a bug...

Comment: With ::1, it is working.

Comment: If I omit the zone specifier, then bind() does not work (it seems to fill the sockaddr_in6::sin6_scope_id field).

Comment: If you use link-local address then you have to specify interface name as @jørgensen said

Answer (score 0):

It's only a problem with Red Hat and with *link-local* scope. When using an address with global scope, its working.

I tried out with Ubuntu 10.4, here it is working also with link-local adddresses.

This is my Red Hat Distribution:
    [root@BETESIP02 sipp]# uname -a
    Linux BETESIP02 2.6.18-194.el5PAE #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 22:00:21 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux